# how to disprove that a function is in the big O of another function

Tags: proof-verification, asymptotics

how can we choose two functions f and g such that $\\$
f $\in O(g)$
But $\sum_0^n f(n) \notin O(n*g(n))$

Comment: What? Sometimes it *is*.

Comment: What if $f = 0$ or something, for example? You have to rule out certain trivialities before you state the problem. As it stands, it is false.

Comment: A better way to put it might be, "find $f$ such that $f \in O(g)$
but $\sum_0^n f(n) \notin O(n\, g(n))$."

Comment: @David K that's what i meant

Comment: There are nontrivial examples where it is false, like $f(n)=g(n)=n$.  Please check your question.  There is an edit button at the bottom that will let you correct it.

Comment: @user488870 Thank you for clarifying. You can see here, that when you do not mention your question properly, the comments and answers may not wait for you to clarify, but may carry on with their own interpretations, which makes it a problem when you actually do state the right problem. Please edit the question.

Comment: @user488870 Also $\,\sum_0^n f(n)\,$ as written is just $\,(n+1) \cdot f(n)\,$. You likely meant $\,\sum_{k=0}^n f(\color{red}{k})\,$ instead.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:   consider for example $\,f(n)=g(n)=\dfrac{1}{n+1}\,$.